# How to identify backend database when using Perl's DBI::ODBC

Tags: perl, odbc, dbi

I'm writing a function in a module that receives a DBI database handle object.  Often, this is an ODBC connection.  When I run:

```
print $dbh->{Driver}{Name};
```

I get `ODBC`.  How can I tell to what type of database that ODBC connection refers?  Sometimes it's MySQL, others it's DB2 or MSSQL.

Versions:

- CentOS Linux 7.3
- Perl 5.16.3
- DBD::ODBC 1.50
- unixODBC 2.3.1

Comment: Maybe `$dbh->get_info`?

Comment: @ikegami Yes, it needs the right argument, but $dbh->get_info(17) returns what I want.  Thank you.